# Where does the content of a bulk sms get stored?

Tags: sms, activity, civisms

Emails, pdf's, and single sms get their content stored in the field "Details" in the activity.

That is evidently not happening with bulk sms. Where do CiviCRM store the content of a bulk sms that has been sent out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

It is stored in the table civicrm_mailing as body_text or body_html

Comment: It would probably be possible to write a post hook to copy it into the details though.

Comment: @DaveFF For consistency of data and usability for back-end-users, it would probably be a good solution to fix that, yes:-)